# Flajaxian File Upload control not uploading files in FireFox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

Currently I have developed a website in asp.net using vb.net
I needed to upload multiple files at once, So I used Flajaxian File Upload Control to do my job.

It works great in any version of Internet Explorer.
But in Firefox it shows that it has uploaded files but none of my files are uploaded.

I think there might be some settings in web.config or in the control itself.
Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Can you post your code please, are you using any extra javascript on your page?

Comment: no I don't use any extra javascript on my page and the code for file upload is fup(I).saveas(.........) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have googled for that and I found that this control is not compatible with firefox. I think it works well with IE. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solve your problem 
but you can try Jquery File Uplaod

[jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html)